# How do I use visible bindings with radio button observable parameter?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

The correct radio button is selected when this page renders, but the additional inputs should appear when either "sendemail" or "sms" radio button values are selected, right?

```
$(function () {
    var rbViewModel = {
        qrType: ko.observable('plaintext')
    };
    ko.applyBindings(rbViewModel);
});
```

Then my radio buttons

```html
<input type="radio" name="txtType" value="plaintext" data-bind="checked: qrType" />Plaintext
<input type="radio" name="txtType" value="sendemail" data-bind="checked: qrType" />Send E-mail
<input type="radio" name="txtType" value="sms" data-bind="checked: qrType" />SMS
```

And my inputs:

```html
<div data-bind="visible: qrType == 'sendemail'"><input type="text" id="txtEmailSubject" placeholder="E-mail subject" /></div>
<div data-bind="visible: qrType == 'sendemail'"><input type="text" id="txtEmailBody" placeholder="E-mail body" /></div>
<div data-bind="visible: qrType == 'sms'"><input type="text" id="txtSmsMsg" placeholder="SMS body" /></div>
```

Is there something wrong with the attribute on the `div` elements? I thought functions were able to be used in the visible bindings per KnockoutJS [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html), like this:

```
data-bind="visible: qrType=='sendemail'"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use an observable in an expression in a data-bind attribute, you need to reference it with ().

They would need to look like: `visible: qrType() === 'sendemail'`